# User defined messages in maven output

Tags: maven, maven-2

Is it possible to define own messages to print out to maven output? I mean, if something goes wrong with maven build, like a missing dependency, am I able to print out some king of handy message after/before BUILD FAILED message? Also, is there a way to rewrite BUILD FAILED message to fit to my needs?

Cheers

Comment: As far as i know it is not. But the question is why do you need it? What is the purpose?

Comment: In our project, there's a failed build after every release, because of some dependency issues, but these issues can be solved to first run 'clean' (in short..). I want to print out a handy message what to do in such cases. Sure, it would be better to solve the original problem, but there's not enough resource for tracking down the problem atm. The problem only occurs when you build the project on local machine.

Comment: Example: Newcomer tries to build the project locally, using the local environment. There was a release yesterday, so our newcomer should build the project with 'clean dist' first to avoid dependency issues, but he/she happens to forget this. In this case, if a failed build would print out a handy message for him to try clean dist would solve the problem.

Comment: Just give him/her a basic Maven introduction which results in using `mvn clean package` first and should run without any failure which mean 'BUILD SUCESS'. It sounds you are trying to prevent good introduction into the basics of Maven.

Comment: What I can think of is using the enforcer plugin, which has a bunch of [rules](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html), some of which might offer you a solution. Perhaps you can fail when a certain file is missing or something. Some of these offer "an optional message to the user if the rule fails", so there you go! The failure conditions aren't stated in the question well enough to give more specific advise.